# Есть ли либа для перевода текста?

Tags: android, android-studio, кодировка

Добрый день! У меня есть **EditText**, в который юзер пишет название города. Строго на русском. По нажатию на кнопку, отправляется запрос на сервер. Но с кириллицей как-то некорректно выводит ответ на запрос. Есть ли какая-либо библиотека, умеющая переводить текст прямо в студио? Или надо подключаться к api переводчика какого-нибудь?

Comment: Может, вам всё-таки стоит научиться работать с юникодом (он включает кириллицу)? Иначе вы так всё время от него будете бегать.

Comment: @ NickVolynkin если я конвертирую кириллицу в юникод, то теоретически, запрос пройдет?

Comment: Давайте сначала отделим теплое от мягкого. Кириллица — это просто набор абстрактных букв. Они не существуют как байты в памяти. Чтобы как-то сохранить текст в кириллице или в любом другом алфавите (включая латиницу), нужна кодировка — способ назначить каждой букве какое-то уникальное представление в байтах.

Comment: Причина того, что программа "некорректно выводит ответ на запрос" вероятно в том, что где-то ваш текст закодирован с помощью одной кодировки, а программа пытается его раскодировать с помощью другой.

Comment: Поэтому, пожалуйста, покажите код ваш, который отправляет и получает запрос. Особенно место, где вы берете строку из EditText и отправляете ее, а также где получаете и как-то отображаете.